How to override a query variable to be not set for a given scenario when it is set using background
I am trying to upgrade karate version from 0.9.6 to 1.4 and i am trying to see how can i update my existing code. I have a param which needs to be set for all scenarios in feature file so i am setting it in background. there are quite some tests in feature file and in one of them i dont want above param to be there so in karate 0.9.6 i was removing that param in given scenario like this And param clientId = (null) and it was working fine.
With karate 1.4 above is not working so trying to see what are my options.
here is how my feature file looks like:
Feature: Testing
Background:
* param clientId = 'test123'
Scenario 1: testing that param is there
... works fine
Scenario 2: testing that param is not there
Given path '/actuator/info'
And param clientId = (null)
When method GET
Then status 200
Expected : scenario 2's whole url would be something like <server>/actuator/info but it is taking value from background and url is <server>/actuator/info?clientId=test123

If it is null it should be removed. Follow this process if you think there is a bug - which is unlikely.
Try this to confirm:
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* param foo = null
* method get

And you can see the param is not sent.
By the way, old versions are not supported.
EDIT: OP wants to do some over-riding of the Background. This is not supported for the HTTP "builder" actually, the only workaround I can think of is this:
Feature:

Background:
  * def fooValue = 'bar'

Scenario:
  * url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
  * def fooValue = null
  * param foo = fooValue
  * method get

Maybe just creating different feature files or scenarios without a background is the way to go.

Peter, if param is set using background than overwriting/removing it in given scenario using above example you said does not work. It still uses param value which is there in background

here is how my full feature file looks like:
`Feature: Testing
Background:

url 'https://google.com'
param clientId = 'test123'

Scenario: Test without param clientId
Given url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
And param clientId = null
When method GET
Then status 200`


@Pman doing this kind of "undo" of HTTP keywords is not supported. see my answer edit.

so do you mean only option is to not set in background and set in all scenarios where needed except the one where it is not needed ?

@Pman yes, or use variables. it should not be too hard either way

just read your edit.. thank you for your prompt reply
